# Visualizing system load average with Kibana 4.1

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I have a Kibana search that returns the load average in a field called metric_value_number. This indexed field has a format of Number, and a Numeral.js format pattern of "0,0.[00]". This is default values.

Here is a screenshot of my search with sample data

[image: Kibana Search]

When I try to make a visualization with a sum-aggregation, it gets aggregated to zero. This applies to Visualization types of at least Line chart, Area chart and Metric.

**How can I properly visualize the system average load with the data I have?**

[image: Kibana Visualization]

[image: Kibana Metric Visualization]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this thread, because I had some trouble myself getting our load visualized. However, it turns out I had to type cast to number first by using `%{NUMBER:load_1:float}` and actually needed an `average` aggregation. 
Had to delete the Logstash index and "reload the field list" in Kibana to get it working.

Tried to reproduce your problem by using your settings. Unfortunately for you, I got it working. I am currently using Kibana Version 4.1.2-snapshot
Build 7500.

[image: Discover]
[image: Visualize]

Comment: Thanks! Will check this out one of the nearest days.